# modify xml stored in varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've this table in a legacy system

```
CREATE TABLE Tmp (Content VARCHAR(MAX)) -- Note it's VARCHAR instead of XML
GO

INSERT INTO Tmp
VALUES ('<Result><Tag>tag1</Tag></Result>')
GO
```

How can I remove the `Tag` element from the table? I am aware that I can use the following sql if `Content` is `XML` but it's not working for 'VARCHAR'.

```
UPDATE tmp 
SET Content.MODIFY('delete /Result/Tag[1]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Linger inspired me to use `REPLACE`...

```
UPDATE Tmp
SET Content = Replace(Content,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(XML, Content).query('/Result/Tag[1]'))
        ,'')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Tmp
SET content = REPLACE(REPLACE(content, '<Tag>', ''), '</Tag>', '')
```

EDIT:

```
UPDATE Tmp
SET content =
LEFT(content, CHARINDEX('<Tag>', content) - 1) + 
RIGHT(content, LEN(content) - CHARINDEX('</Tag>', content) - 5)
```

Comment: This results `<Result>tag1</Result>`, when I say remove the element, I mean removing the tag name ,the text content and child elements

Comment: **@lastr2d2** see my edit.  Is that more of what you are after?

Comment: **@lastr2d2**, I made one last edit. It should have been `- 5` instead of `+ 6`.